# Exclude Duplicate Objects in django queryset

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have model called StudentAppeared

```
class StudentAppeared(models.Model):
    roll_number = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Assume i have following data

[image]

From the above data result should display

[image]

How can i achieve this thing using django query for ***StudentAppeared*** model?

Answer (score 5):

```
StudentAppeared.objects.distinct()
```

sorry made a mistake. fixed it

Comment: This returns all five rows as the ids are distinct.

Comment: Also take into consideration too that this doesn't work on SQLite backends (if you are in development)

Answer (score 2):

This returns unique `roll_number`s with the highest associated `id`, sorted by `id`:

```
from django.db.models import Max

stats = (
    StudentAppeared.objects
    .values('roll_number')
    .annotate(max_id=Max('id'))
    .values_list('max_id', 'roll_number ')
    .order_by('max_id')
)
```